# How to use table twice in entity framework?

Tags: c#

How to write this query in entity framework?

```
SELECT * FROM [Account]
where [Account].[AccountID] not in (select [Account].[ParentID] from [Account])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
from a in db.Account
where !db.Account.Any(a2 => a2.ParentID == a.AccountID)
select a;
```